# LINQ with subquery, group by and having count

Tags: c#, linq

I've just begun to start writing queries with LINQ, that's why I'm not very familiar with it. My query works pretty well in SQL but I would like to replace it in its LINQ expression.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Libelle
FROM Question, Connaissance
WHERE Question.ID_Q = Connaissance.ID_Question and ID_Q = (SELECT ID_Question
FROM Connaissance
GROUP BY ID_Question
HAVING COUNT(ID_Reponse) >= ALL(SELECT COUNT(ID_Reponse)
FROM Connaissance
GROUP BY ID_Question))
```

*(Libelle is the name of the Question in the Question table)*

I tried something like that :

```
var question = from q in dc.Question
               join a in dc.Connaissance on q.ID_Q equals a.ID_Question
               group q by a.ID_Question into grp
               where grp.Count() >= ???
```

The problem is that I don't know how to convert this part : `>= ALL(SELECT COUNT(ID_Reponse)`. I tried to search things like that on the Internet, but didn't find anything.

If anybody could help me, I would be very grateful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future it will help to state the expected result.  From what I can tell

```
(SELECT ID_Question
FROM Connaissance
GROUP BY ID_Question
HAVING COUNT(ID_Reponse) >= ALL(SELECT COUNT(ID_Reponse)
FROM Connaissance
GROUP BY ID_Question))
```

is just getting a list of question ids for all the questions with the most answers. Since the `ALL` in this part ensures only those questions that have an answer count that is greater than or equal to all of the answer counts for all questions.

```
COUNT(ID_Reponse) >= ALL(SELECT COUNT(ID_Reponse)
FROM Connaissance
GROUP BY ID_Question)
```

So, with the understanding you are wanting the name of all the questions that tie with the most answers, try this

```
var maxAnswerCount = dc.Connaissance.GroupBy(answer => answer.ID_Question)
                                    .Select(answerGroup => answerGroup.Count())
                                    .Max();

var questions = (from answer in dc.Connaissance
                 group answer by answer.ID_Question into answerGroup
                 where answerGroup.Count() == maxAnswerCount
                 from question in dc.Question
                 where answerGroup.Key == question.ID_Q
                 select question.Libelle).Distinct()
```

of course, if I haven't understood what the end result is, please clarify.

Comment: I promise that I'll do it next time!
You've perfectly understood what I would like to do. But when I try to put your query in my code, the last line doesn't work. It's written that "question" from question.Libelle doesn't exist in such a context. I keep trying!

Comment: @Sol This is actually the same situation as the other answer. If you like this way better, you can just modify it a tad like so:
`var result = (from question in dc.Question
                             join answer in dc.Connaissance on question.ID_Q equals answer.ID_Question
                             group answer by answer.ID_Question into answerGroup
                             where answerGroup.Count() == maxAnswerCount
                             select answerGroup).Distinct().First() as Question;`

Comment: @Allen I get it, but... (still a "but"), when I try then to display in a label the result of the query (result.Libelle), I have the "System.NullReferenceException" error. I feel completely stupid haha, sorry for that. I'm going to look for fixing it ~

Comment: @Sol I updated the last code block to bring the question table in later in the query.  This should resolve most of the issues you've had -- although, still typing code in the answer box so there may be some rough edges yet.

Comment: Also, I'm not convinced the original SQL returns a single result -- except when, by circumstance, there is only one question with max answer count.  So I have left the a restriction to a single result off of my answer.  More information would be needed to know which name to return when there are more than one question with the same number of answers (the max count).

Comment: It works!!!!!! I'm so so so happy! Thanks a lot for having kept on helping me, I'm very grateful. You (David, Allen, Enigmativity) are the best!

Comment: No problem, and welcome to the site.  To wrap up the question and help those who come later, be sure to _up vote_ the answers that helped and -- when (if) the question is fully resolved -- mark the one that resolved it.

Comment: (I didn't try the case in which 2 answers could be possible. I will try it later, but in my case, it has a little interest)

Answer (score 1):

Would this do it?

```
var question =
    from q in dc.Question
    join a in dc.Connaissance on q.ID_Q equals a.ID_Question
    group q by a.ID_Question into grp
    where grp.Count() >= dc.Connaissance.Select(y => y.ID_response).Distinct().Count()
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for trying!
I replaced it, but it still doesn't work. It's written that I need a select clause after the last one. I should put in it the "Libelle" of the question...

Comment: @Sol
Do you mean your getting the compile error: "A query body must end with a select clause or group clause"?
If so, you can just add "select grp;" to the end of Enigmativity's answer.

This will return you an IGrouping<int, Question>.

Comment: [More information on using the IGrouping result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Allen, yes I do! Thanks a lot. I thought I would have just one question at the end, and not something like an interface. How could I just have the only one element I'm looking for? (Sorry for still asking, I'm so new with that...)

Comment: @Sol - Your original query didn't identify how to select `Libelle` so I left it out, but yes you need either `select q.Libelle` or `select a.LIbelle` to complete the query.

Comment: @Sol the result is an IEnumerable, so we can call First on it to get the first (and in this case only) object. Casting it to Question gives us access to the field you want. Console.WriteLine(((Question)question.First()).Libelle);

To be honest though, a rewrite like David Culp suggested could make this section of code more easily understood, and possibly much more performant.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped :). I took inspiration from what David wrote as your query was a little complicated for me. But maybe when I become more and more skilled, I'll take parts from it ~

Comment: @Sol - Can you tell me what was a little complicated in `dc.Connaissance.Select(y => y.ID_response).Distinct().Count()`? I'm happy to help explain it if you need.

Comment: @Enigmativity, it's just the global syntax with which I'm not very familiar... Because everything is super condensed, and I didn't see the different parts in it..

Comment: @Sol - "Global syntax"?

Comment: @Enigmativity : the last line is something of a mystery. I mean by "global syntax", the order in which we have to put the different elements, the writing. But as I've worked on LINQ since the last time, I came along. Now I have a new problem, I asked there something different : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386320/linq-query-with-a-list-vs-splitting-database
Don't know if you could help me ~